# Find minimum in sorted array, which was shifted

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-search

Interview question: 
A sorted array has been rotated so that the elements might appear in the order  3456712. How would you find the minimum element? You may assume that the array has all unique elements

It is need to implement modified binary search algorithm.
First(incorrect solution) in C++:

```
int findMin(int a[], unsigned int leftIndex, unsigned int rightIndex)
{
    while(leftIndex <= rightIndex)
    {
        unsigned int mid = leftIndex + (rightIndex - leftIndex) / 2;
        if(leftIndex  == rightIndex) return a[rightIndex];
        if(a[rightIndex] > a[mid] && a[leftIndex] > a[mid]) 
        {
            ++leftIndex; 
            rightIndex = mid;
        }
        if(a[rightIndex] > a[mid]) rightIndex = --mid;
        if(a[rightIndex] < a[mid]) leftIndex = ++mid;
    }
}
```

Second implementation in Java of looking for minimum in sorted array, which was shifted. It passed unit tests. Please, let me know about bugs, if you find them in Java implementation.

```
class Test
{
    static public int findMin(int a[], int leftIndex, int rightIndex)
    {
        while(leftIndex <= rightIndex)
        {
            int mid = leftIndex + (rightIndex - leftIndex) / 2;

            if(leftIndex == rightIndex) return a[rightIndex];
            if(rightIndex - leftIndex == 1) return Math.min(a[leftIndex], a[rightIndex]);
            if(a[rightIndex] > a[mid]) rightIndex = mid;
            if(a[rightIndex] < a[mid]) leftIndex =  mid;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int a1 [] = {1};
        System.out.println(findMin(a1,0,0));

        int a2 [] = {1,2};
        int a3 [] = {2, 1};
        System.out.println(findMin(a2,0,1));
        System.out.println(findMin(a3,0,1));

        int a4 [] = {1, 2, 3};
        int a5 [] = {2, 3, 1};
        int a6 [] = {3, 1, 2};
        System.out.println(findMin(a4,0,2));
        System.out.println(findMin(a5,0,2));
        System.out.println(findMin(a6,0,2));

        int a7 [] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        int a8 [] = {2, 3, 4, 1};
        int a9 [] = {3, 4, 1, 2};
        int a10 [] = {4, 1, 2, 3};
        System.out.println(findMin(a7,0,3));
        System.out.println(findMin(a8,0,3));
        System.out.println(findMin(a9,0,3));
        System.out.println(findMin(a10,0,3));
    }
}
```

Recursive implementation in Java:

```
static public int findMin(int a[], int leftIndex, int rightIndex)
    {
            int mid = leftIndex + (rightIndex - leftIndex) / 2;
            if(leftIndex == rightIndex) return a[rightIndex];
            if(rightIndex - leftIndex == 1) return Math.min(a[leftIndex], a[rightIndex]);
            if(a[rightIndex] > a[mid]) return findMin(a, leftIndex, mid);
            if(a[rightIndex] < a[mid]) return findMin(a, mid, rightIndex);
            return -1;
    }
```

Comment: We share code with colleagues here, and we are trying to check - is this implementation correct.

Comment: I've added your comment into the question - those without a clear problem statement may be off-topic on this site. I've also added some tags - they help experts find your question - but I'm not sure about the language you're working with.

Comment: For this kind of algorithmic task, a test-driven approach tends to work very well.  Write a couple of simple tests first, and work up from there.  I find that the test-driven approach helps me ask questions like "_What API should I present?_",  "_Can the input array be empty or null?_" and  "_Should I make it generic to work with any element type - or any container type?_"  Considering that this arose from an interview question, bringing up those considerations can make a candidate stand out as having a grasp of the whole problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Unfortunately the code is not correct as it stands. I made a simple test and the program did not return (infinite loop).

Some of the problems I noticed:

```
unsigned int mid = leftIndex + (leftIndex + rightIndex) / 2;
```

You want the middle in between. So why are you adding `leftIndex`?

Then

```
if(a[rightIndex] < a[mid]) leftIndex = ++mid;
```

Why `++mid`? 
Then

```
if(a[rightIndex] > a[mid] && a[leftIndex] > a[mid]) 
        {
            ++leftIndex; 
            rightIndex = mid;
        }
```

I didn't think it through, but I think this case should not be a separate one.
Then

```
if(a[rightIndex] > a[mid]) rightIndex = mid;
```

should probably be `>=` rather than just `>` (think about repeated values).

The rough idea you want to implement is:

```
If leftIndex val is smaller than mid, then leftIndex=mid.
If rightIndex val is larger than mid, then rightIndex=mid.
When the indices meet (or are neighbours of each other) you found the min.
```

Now try it yourself. Only if you don't get it right on your own you should continue reading.

I adapted your code a bit to get it working:

```
int findMin(int a[], unsigned int leftIndex, unsigned int rightIndex)
{
    if(a[leftIndex] < a[rightIndex]){
      //then the array is perfectly sorted (i.e. shifted k*size_of_array for any integer k) 
      //hence we return the first element.
      return a[leftIndex];
    }
    while(leftIndex <= rightIndex)
    {
        unsigned int mid = leftIndex + (rightIndex - leftIndex) / 2;
        if((leftIndex  == rightIndex) || (leftIndex+1 == rightIndex))
        {
         return a[rightIndex];
        }
        if(a[leftIndex] <= a[mid]) leftIndex = mid;
        if(a[rightIndex] >= a[mid]) rightIndex = mid;
    }
}
```

Note 1: I haven't fully tested this code. So it might not be bullet proof. But it worked for some simple examples. I might test some cornercases when I have more time at my hands.

Note 2: One could clean up the code further. But I wanted to still stay close to your snippet.